# A message box before a user deletes a row (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

How could I make a VBA code to show a message box before a user tries to delete an entire row? I'm making a file for work and I want to ensure that the user is sure about deleting a row.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just let the user mark it for deletion, then check it later in the code and delete if valid. Then you can hide it etc

Comment: There is no way to prevent the user deleting a row. There is no event that triggers before deleting a row. The only thing you can do is add a button "delete row" and make your question there. But this does not prevent the user from using normal row delete built-in in Excel.

Comment: In addition to @Pᴇʜ: you could lock the worksheet, then, with the "delete row" button, you only delete the row if user chooses ok.

Comment: @Ike While this will work, the downside is that it might lock other things too (not only deleting rows). So it highly depends on how the worksheet is used in general.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ that's definitly right - e.g. sorting won't be possible. As always: it depends what has to be achieved in the specific use case

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Right now the file is locked almost entirely, only a few actions are allowed. But what I understand from your answers, there really isn't a way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve. I was hoping to get the message box right before deleting the row (i.e choose a row, right click and when pressing delete, the message prompts). But I have to think something else then.

Comment: @user15012453 you can achieve what you describe only by a custom button (but not the default delete).